# Restore Deleted files ubuntu one

Tags: files, restore

I have accidentally deleted all my files on my one account two days ago.  I can still see them in
https://edge.one.ubuntu.com/files/trash/root/

but when I click restore, the service is down.  Will i ever be able to get my files back, or is there another way to restore them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu One doesn't provide a way to restore your files but if you cantact the team them should be able to restore the files for you https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem, but I realized that all the files removed go to the Trash in all the devices that are synchronized, so you just have to recover them from there.

If you can't find your files on the Trash, you can contact Ubuntu One support directly at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ mentioning which folders you need recovered, and that they are not on your Trash.